# How to send and retrive data from php to java/android?

Tags: java, php, android, https

I am building this demo project in android for temporary use.I need to run query on server database and return result from that.I am stuck at retriving data from server part. This are my files.
MainActivity :

```
public void callit(View view) {
    final String url = "http://xyz.000webhostapp.com/login.php?mail=abcxyz@gmail.com";
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

                    try {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                        String json = reader.readLine();
                        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json);
                        JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is my Toast message!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    //Closes the connection.
                    try {
                        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e)
            {

            }
            catch (IOException e)
                e.printStackTrace();
            {

            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

And this is my php script file :

```
    <?php

define('HOST_NAME','localhost');
define('USER_NAME','abc');
define('PASSWORD','xyz');
define('DATABASE','pqr');


$con = mysqli_connect(HOST_NAME,USER_NAME,PASSWORD,DATABASE);

if(!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_erro());

}
else
{

        $email = $_GET["mail"];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' ";
        $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if(!empty($result))
        {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                $response["mb"]=$row["mobile"];
            }
            echo(json_encode($response));
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

But i dont know how exactly this data is going to store in json file? As you can see from php file i just need to return mobile number of given email id from database. And php script is just working fine i tested it in browser.

I just need to find out a way to send this value to my android app and toast that mobile number.

Ask if any part of my question feel ambiguous. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: look for building a rest api in php, or if security( or proper doing the things) is not much of a concern if its a school project then simply you dnt need to  convert it to a json , 
just in your php file ,create a simple php page, where you get phone number as a query parameter $email = $_GET["mail"]; like this which you are already getting, just grab the page from android simple you dnt need to convert it to json

Comment: But how data will go from server to android file..I am newbie at both android and php.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/ this might be of your use.

Comment: just like a browser , you can echo it, and grab the page, if you get any html tags you can remove them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its good if you develop a rest api in php,[here](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/) is an example online tutorial attached for rest, or if security( or proper doing the things) is not much of a concern if its a school project then simply you dnt need to convert it to a json , just in your php file ,create a simple php page, where you get phone number as a query parameter $email = $_GET["mail"]; like this which you are already getting, just grab the page from android simple you dnt need to convert it to json
here is the Simple PHP program that echos phone number and java code that grabs that phone number

```
<?php
echo "00923244549369"
?>
```

in your code you will echo the phone number at the end just like it

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    URL url;
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader br;
    String line;

    try {
        url = new URL("http://localhost/writers/");
        is = url.openStream(); // throws an IOException
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception mue) {
        mue.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // nothing to see here
        }
    }

}
```

output: **00923244549369**

Comment: Thanks for your Help.!

Comment: you are welcome please click on tick mark if the answer helped